Can I replace a 3-way light switch with single-pole switch with motion sensor?
I have three 3-way light switches controlling a hallway light. I want to install one motion sensor switch to the hallway. I believe this will be sufficient and I will not need the other two 3-way switches (one at each end of the hallway). They can be non-functional or dead.
My question is: can I use a single-pole switch (Lutron Maestro Motion Sensor, 2 amp) for this purpose? If so, what wiring do I need in the switch that I am installing and in those two others un-needed switches?
I already have bought single-pole Lutron Maestro. I can return this and pay almost double to get 3-way motion sensor switch if it is indeed necessary.

You have 3 switches. Two of those are 3-way and one is 4-way. The good news is that most likely you can put this in place of any of the three switches, because the Lutron Maestro Motion Sensor, or at least model MS-OPS2H-WH, does not require neutral but can use either ground or neutral.

Turn off the circuit breaker
Open up all 3 switches and pull out, but do not disconnect, the switches to get pictures showing all the wires going into each switch and showing which wires are in which cables.
Carefully turn on the breaker and
Use a non-contact voltage tester or a multimeter to figure out which wire/cable is the source of power from the panel. Doing that will be easiest with the light off but even then it could get confusing.
Turn off the circuit breaker.

That should be enough to figure this out. Once we know which wire is hot (in one of the 3-way), which wire is switched hot (in the other 3-way) and which wires are travelers, it should not be too hard to figure out how to make this work.
The key is going to be to retask one of the travelers as hot (line) and one as switched hot (load), though it will vary a bit depending on where the new switch will be installed. In the two boxes where the switches will be removed, a traveler (which now won't be a traveler) will be connected directly to the wire going to the common (if 3-way) or matching traveler (if 4-way).
To be continued once we have pictures.

Some non contact testers are just enough to tell you there is power in the box, but not good enough to tell which wire is hot.

@crip659 True. Which is one reason why I said or a multimeter. Both have their uses. But while I've had multimeters "forever" (using them primarily for low voltage electronics before I got more into DIY home improvements) many other people don't have one but may have an NCVT as a safety-checker.
